# Automating new MySQL users - LiveCode app

Tags: mysql, livecode

I have an On- Rev account and have been establishing new MySQL users through cPanel. I copy an existing database template when establishing a new user. These users are then able to store and retrieve data entered into their IOS apps (created with Livecode) using a username and password I send to them by email.
The above works very well but is time consuming to administer. Is it possible for new users to create a SQL database with username and password direct from the app? And to be able to request password changes again direct from the app, with everything automated, or is this wishful thinking?

Comment: Your database design is wrong. The user name and password of the database are only for you, not for the users of your app. Your approach makes your entire system vulnerable. You need to add a new table with user names and encrypted passwords. A new user is registered when his user name and password are entered in the table. In the main table, you can now add records for this user.

Comment: Thanks Mark that makes sense... I do you have example code for me to get this to work.